# Google Maps KML Layer not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 90%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://ec2-54-198-148-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/webapp/public/kmlfiles/LargeCoordinates.kml',
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMtoh9P3UkoxbXndKu_HOP7KsVwTRvxGU&callback=initMap">
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The KML present here - http://ec2-54-198-148-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/webapp/public/kmlfiles/LargeCoordinates.kml is not shown on the map.

All my other KML files work ok, just not this one. I believe this is because there are many coordinates in the KML file.

Any help to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: As @ChristiaanAdams indicated, your KML is invalid.  If I add the missing tags and remove the partial coordinate, the [file works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/LargeCoordinatesA.kml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 5th placemark/polygon (the big one), the line with the geometry/coordinates seems to be truncated.  First clue is that there appear to be missing tags at the end of the line.  It ends with only the `</MultiGeometry>` tag, when it needs to end with: `</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>`.
Looking more closely at the last set of coordinates, they appear to be cut off, ending after the decimal point in the 2nd number:  `-96.697594,46.`

So you'll need to at least add the appropriate tags to close out the line, and probably fix the last coordinate pair (or just remove it).  That should give you a valid KML file which should load (so long as the geometry isn't too big for Maps).  You'll also want to check the source data to see if additional coordinates are missing from that line, and if so, figure out how to get them back.

To help others with similar issues, do you know how that KML was generated? With what software? Maybe something that can only handle so many characters in the coordinate string?

Comment: Thank you! I wrote custom code to create KML causing this issue. It is sorted now.